# PHP over trim! Text disappearing! But why?

Tags: php, wordpress

I just want to display the categories for my blog posts, but to SOME of the categories (and especially if they stand alone, the last bit get's trimmed away ~ "Music" becomes "Mu", and "Adventure" becomes "Adventur" ... any help? Please!

```
// Category boxes :P
function showcatz() {
global $post;

echo '<div class="categz_wrapper"><div class="categz">';

// get the category IDs assigned to post
$categories = wp_get_post_categories( $post->ID, array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
// separator between links
$separator = '</div><div class="categz"> ';

    if ( $categories ) {

    // List categories  
    $cat_ids = implode( ',' , $categories );

    // Remove ONE category from the list
    $kill = array("411,", "411");
    $killit = str_replace($kill, "", $cat_ids);

    $cats = wp_list_categories( 'title_li=&style=none&echo=0&include=' . $killit);
    $cats = rtrim( trim( str_replace( '<br />',  $separator, $cats ) ), $separator );

    // Only show categories if there is any
    if ( $killit ) { echo $cats; }

    }

echo '</div></div>';

}
```

Comment: Because [trim()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) removes every individual character that appears in the $separator list of characters, which includes `d`, `i`, `v`, `c`, `l`, `a`, `s`, `g`, `z`, etc

Comment: To go with Mark Baker's comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your passing a parameter to rtrim called `$separator` which has the value `</div><div class="categz">` so when the following statement is executed it will remove the following `chars` from your string. `div<>clastegz`

```
rtrim( str_replace( '<br />',  $separator, $cats ) ), $separator );
```

Solution, remove the second parameter to `rtrim`

Comment: Close, it's actually the outer `rtrim` that's getting passed the separator. This has the same result though.